# Make working WC_Order get_item_count() method on "woocommerce_new_order" hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

When I use the action **'woocommerce_new_order'** to get the order item count it always returns zero.

When I do the same thing using other hooks like **'woocommerce_thankyou'** it works properly. Why it doesn't work with **'woocommerce_new_order**?

My code is:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', function( $order_id ){
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    //Returns zero. Don't know why
    error_log($order->get_item_count());
} );
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using this hook:

**'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed'**